# Store input into variables Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

This might be a stupid question but I haven't been able to do it since yesterday. 
I got an input file that contains some data that I need to work with, and it should look like this:

```
x <= 42 & x >= 20 | x < 50 
y > 10 & y < 20 
z < 100 & z > 101 
y > 5 
w <= 0 
a >= 0 | a <= 10
```

I need to be able to separate it into instructions, following this format: `<variable> <operator> <number>`, and each of this instructions is separated, as you can see, by either a '&', a '|' or a new line (which in my case means the same as '|').

Note that the `x` variable appears in 2 different lines but it refers to the same `x`, one should not overwrite the other.

My wild guess is to iterate through the the text and split it into chunks of 4 strings, and that would be it. The problem with that is that I don't know how to deal with new lines in Ruby.

I tried:

```
lines = []


begin
  file = File.open(ARGV.at(0))

  while (t = file.gets.chomp)
    lines << line.split
  end


  file.close
rescue => e
  puts e
end
```

And that would return and array of lines, each split into words, but I still need to get the newline.

TL;DR: Given the previous input, I need to be able to do something like:

```
x = (LeftInfinite.new(42,']').intersection(RightInfinite.new('[',20).union(LeftInfinite.new(50,')')
```

For the first line for example

Comment: Is this the expected output, or is this an input?

Comment: That's how the file I'm reading from looks like.

Comment: Can you share what the desired output should look like? Please..

Comment: I don't need to show an output yet, all I'm looking for is a way to say variable x, operator1 =>, number 42, operator2 &, for example. What I'm thinking now is to iterate through each line and use the % operator to get everything and if ` line.length % 4 == 3`   I would just add an '|' which is the same as a newline. I haven't done this yet.

Comment: Still unclear. Are you trying to read the infile and generate an out file from it "modified version"? Or storing it in a variable/array . either way. What do you want the new format to look like ?  Also, "|" is not the same as new line. It is a delimiter and not a new line.

Comment: Have a look at the variety of arguments available with [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split).

Comment: OK, giving some context, I have to build some sort of interval calculator, in order to do that I have to build the intervals, and to do that I need at least, a variable to store the interval, the operator1 which will tell me if the interval is closed or not, and a number to know where am i truncating the interval, operator2 is used for defining operation intersection and union. Also, I know "|"is not the same as newline, but as I stated in my question, it "means" the same to the program, so I'm adding a "|" to the end of each line but the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can read  file's content by lines

`File.readlines(ARGV.at(0)).each do |line|`

or get all content and split it

`lines = File.read(ARGV.at(0)).split("\n")`

Above is good for small files because a file's content loaded into memory.
For big files need use this approach

```
File.foreach(ARGV.at(0)).with_index do |line, line_num|

end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm already reading from a file, my problem is to store the content of those lines into variables I can use.